# Too many connections from this Laravel application / ImageCache

Tags: laravel, caching

On my website made with Laravel, since I use ImageCache, I encounters some connections problems from my mutualised server : it says **"Too many connections from this host" (see exact log below).**

There is a internal limit of 30 simultaneous connections from the same IP on this server. Every time I get an image it consider a new connection so after 30: images are all broken.

Is there a way to bypass that, maybe my cache system isn't well configured ?

Here is the Apache log :

> Rejected, too many connections from this host.
>   (vhost:luxembourgartweek.lu
>   uri:/imagecache/large/1555404894-a19-stand-jarmuschek-partner.jpg
>   current:33 limit:30

Comment: whenever there is a task in which multiple calls to any third party is necessary try using queues

Comment: Hi Malik, thanks you. Actually it's just a call to a script to resize images and display it on the homepage. Do I need a queue for that ?